# HLS with FFmpeg (separated track sync)

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, aac, x264

I'm looking for a solution to proceed transcoding a video file to HLS multi-bitrate with audio track separated

basically, 
I got a video file, I transcoded it into 4 resolutions + 1 audio track

- 180p
- 360p
- 720p
- 1080p
- 2160p (maybe)
- Audio1
- Audio2 (maybe)

but for the exemple, here is my 180p command:

```
ffmpeg -i ${source} \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -b:v 230k -minrate:v 230k -maxrate:v 230k -bufsize:v 200k \
    -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 \
    -x264opts scenecut=0:keyint=75:min-keyint=75 \
    -hls_time 3 \
    -hls_playlist_type vod \
    -r 25 \
    -vf scale=w=320:h=180:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease \
    -an \
    -f hls \
    -hls_segment_filename ../OUT/${base_name}/180p/180p_%06d.ts ../OUT/${base_name}/180p/180p.m3u8
```

and the audio track:

```
ffmpeg -i ${source} \
    -vn \
    -c:a aac \
    -b:a 128k \
    -ar:a 48000 \
    -ac:a 2 \
    -hls_time 3 \
    -hls_playlist_type vod \
    -hls_segment_filename ../OUT/${base_name}/audio1/audio1_%06d.ts ../OUT/${base_name}/audio1/audio1.m3u8
```

for convenient reason, I launch separate ffmpeg command for each resolution, depending on the video source quality

Then I create a standard Master Playlist

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=230000,RESOLUTION=320x180,CODECS="avc1.42001e"
180p/180p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=600000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.42e00a"
360p/360p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=3150000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4d0028"
720p/720p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5000000,RESOLUTION=1920x1080,CODECS="avc1.4d0029"
1080p/1080p.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=128000,CODECS="mp4a.40.2"
audio1/audio1.m3u8
```

When I try to read the Master Playlist, 
I don't have any sound 
Using VLC, the audio track is played before the video tracks

So, How Can I sync Audio track with Video Tracks ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to first encode everything into one file, *then* slice that up with stream-copying into the individual representations (using the HLS muxer).

Comment: Not necessary. However, each program here only makes use of one stream. What the OP needs is the equivalent of 'alternate video rendition'. There are patches on the ML for implementing this via var_stream_map.